# Correct the jquery code to add new file input correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

- List item

I have a use case where glyphicon: '+' button click would add new html input:file-type, but while doing so after two entries, instead of creating one new file_input, multiple are being created.

```js
var firstFileInputClone;

$(document).ready(function() {
  firstFileInputClone =  $(".file-div").last().clone();
});

function addNewFileInput(){

  var newFileElement = firstFileInputClone; 
  var index = $(".file-div").length; 

  $(newFileElement).find("input:first").attr("name","file_" + index);
  $(newFileElement).insertAfter($(".file-div"));
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="file-div row top10">

  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload Attachment</label>  
  <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>       
      <input type="file" name="file_0" class="form-control file-input" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="addNewFileInput()"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you appending that html field ? show that jquery code too

Comment: Edited the code to reflect the problem being faced, run the snippet to see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One.

```js
   function addNewFileInput(){

 var firstFileInputClone = '';
 var index = $(".file-input").length; 
  
 firstFileInputClone += '<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload Attachment</label>';  
 firstFileInputClone +=  '<div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">';
 firstFileInputClone +=  '<div class="input-group">';
 firstFileInputClone +=  '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>'; 
 firstFileInputClone +=  ' <input type="file" name="file_'+index+'" class="form-control file-input" />';
 firstFileInputClone +=  ' <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="addNewFileInput()" ></i></span>';
 firstFileInputClone +=  '</div>';
 firstFileInputClone +=  '</div>';
 
 $('.file-div').append(firstFileInputClone);
 return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="file-div row top10">

  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload Attachment</label>  
  <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>       
      <input type="file" name="file_0" class="form-control file-input" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="addNewFileInput()"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```